# Visual Studio Having a Non Existent Error

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm working in C, and have:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define MIN_YEAR 2012
#define MAX_YEAR 2022 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
}
```

It gives me the error: '#': unexpected in macro definition

And a warning: Mac File format detected: please convert source file to either DOS or UNIX format.

I'm not sure why it's giving me either of those when they work if I copy and paste them into a different C program I've made in the past, or since I've used the repair tool for VS.

Comment: I don't think the repair tool (fixes program installation) would be relevant here (unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean). It sounds like you got this file from somewhere that uses Mac newlines (in at least some places) so Windows is reading your file with at least one of the newlines missing (e.g. `#define MIN_YEAR 2012#define MAX_YEAR 2022` has an unexpected `#` in a macro definition). Since this is so small, you should just be able to delete all your newlines and retype them. Otherwise, paste it into Notepad, make sure it looks right, and then paste it back overtop.

Comment: Classic MacOS (prior to the OS X Mach Unix based versions) used CR for line-ends, whilst UNIX uses LF, and DOS/Windows uses CR+LF.  Most tools can use POSIX/DOS line ends interchangeably (because they both end LF), but less so CR  alone.  Saving the file and explicitly selecting an encoding in the save dialog may fix it.  Some text editors will apply the translation in any event. The question perhaps is how you managed to create such a file in the first instance?  Copy & Pasting from non-plain-text such as a word processor or web page sometimes causes problems.

Comment: It is not really a programming question rather than a how computers and text files work issue.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure why it's giving me either of those when they work if I copy and paste them into a different C program I've made in the past, or since I've used the repair tool for VS.

According to the warning, the problem has to do with the file *format*.  In particular, the relevant difference between Mac (<=9) format, DOS format, and UNIX format is in the bytes used to indicate the end of a line.  Both of the measures that you describe seem plausible ways to resolve such an issue.  In particular, if a "repair tool" solved it then that was surely by performing exactly the conversion recommended by the warning.